# More connections or more connection-pools?

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, database-connection, connection-pooling

Here we have one component which generates different queries for a thousand websites.

This component is deployed on several webservers which hosts hundreds of them. Everything pointed to the same SQL Server.

Well, when we have performance issues, it's hard to find which site is generating the problem.

Due this reason, we've been implementing a strategy that injects the website url on Application Name configuration of the connection string, as shown in the image.

[image: connections]

Well, the question is:

What's better? Having more connections as SRV-SITES-01 (Red mark) or One pool as SRV-SITES-02 (Blue mark).

What's the pro and cons about the two situations?

Thanks,

Armando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one pool you are likely to get more reuse out of the connections. I understand you try to reduce the number of connections. So don't use too many pools.

Use one pool and instrument your application to find out which site is using most resources.